# What is up with the duck?

Tags: support

There is a duck on the bottom right hand corner of my ancient laptop. It comes with me where ever I go. What is the purpose of this duck?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308564/274942.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duck was an [April Fools' joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day). It was a reference to [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), a software engineering practice.

You may find more details about this and past jokes in the [april-fools tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/april-fools) on Meta Stack Exchange.